# Using SuperSLiM Library in nested RecyclerView

Tags: android, nested, android-recyclerview, superslim

I use `SuperSLiM` library from [Github](https://github.com/TonicArtos/SuperSLiM/tree/master)
I need to use this library in nested `RecyclerView`, but when I put this `RecyclerView` which stick's it's header on top, in another `RecyclerView`, it seems that it misses it's properties. 
this is my adapter for root `RecyclerView` that in each row of that I have a `RecyclerView` and a `TextView`.

```
public class Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter.ViewHolder> {


        private Context mContext;
        private LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;


        public Adapter(Context context) {

            this.mContext = context;
            this.mLayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        }


        @Override
        public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {

            View view = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row, viewGroup, false);
            ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);
            return viewHolder;
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {

            //
            RecyclerView mRecyclerView = viewHolder.mRecyclerView;
            TextView mTextView = viewHolder.mTextView;

            //

            mTextView.setText("pos: " + position);

            //set LayoutManager
            mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new NestedLinearLayoutManager(mContext));

            //set Adapter
            CountryNamesAdapter adapter = new CountryNamesAdapter(mContext, 18);
            adapter.setMarginsFixed(true);
            adapter.setHeaderDisplay(18);
            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return 10;
        }

        class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

            TextView mTextView;
            RecyclerView mRecyclerView;

            public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
                super(itemView);

                mTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
                mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.list);


            }
        }
```

This is `NestedLinearLayoutManager` class for showing child `RecyclerView` nice.

```
public class NestedLinearLayoutManager extends LinearLayoutManager {

    public NestedLinearLayoutManager(Context context){
        super(context);
    }
    public NestedLinearLayoutManager(Context context, int orientation, boolean reverseLayout)    {
        super(context, orientation, reverseLayout);
    }

    private int[] mMeasuredDimension = new int[2];

    @Override
    public void onMeasure(RecyclerView.Recycler recycler, RecyclerView.State state,
                          int widthSpec, int heightSpec) {
        final int widthMode = View.MeasureSpec.getMode(widthSpec);
        final int heightMode = View.MeasureSpec.getMode(heightSpec);
        final int widthSize = View.MeasureSpec.getSize(widthSpec);
        final int heightSize = View.MeasureSpec.getSize(heightSpec);
        int width = 0;
        int height = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < getItemCount(); i++) {
            measureScrapChild(recycler, i,
                    View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(i, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
                    View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(i, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
                    mMeasuredDimension);

            if (getOrientation() == HORIZONTAL) {
                width = width + mMeasuredDimension[0];
                if (i == 0) {
                    height = mMeasuredDimension[1];
                }
            } else {
                height = height + mMeasuredDimension[1];
                if (i == 0) {
                    width = mMeasuredDimension[0];
                }
            }
        }
        switch (widthMode) {
            case View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY:
                width = widthSize;
            case View.MeasureSpec.AT_MOST:
            case View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED:
        }

        switch (heightMode) {
            case View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY:
                height = heightSize;
            case View.MeasureSpec.AT_MOST:
            case View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED:
        }

        setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
    }

    private void measureScrapChild(RecyclerView.Recycler recycler, int position, int widthSpec,
                                   int heightSpec, int[] measuredDimension) {
        View view = recycler.getViewForPosition(position);
        if (view != null) {
            RecyclerView.LayoutParams p = (RecyclerView.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
            int childWidthSpec = ViewGroup.getChildMeasureSpec(widthSpec,
                    getPaddingLeft() + getPaddingRight(), p.width);
            int childHeightSpec = ViewGroup.getChildMeasureSpec(heightSpec,
                    getPaddingTop() + getPaddingBottom(), p.height);
            view.measure(childWidthSpec, childHeightSpec);
            measuredDimension[0] = view.getMeasuredWidth() + p.leftMargin + p.rightMargin;
            measuredDimension[1] = view.getMeasuredHeight() + p.bottomMargin + p.topMargin;
            recycler.recycleView(view);
        }
    }
}
```

Does this library work in nested `RecyclerView` too?